# Assign variable name to list in if statement python

Tags: python, list, tuples, arcpy

I apologize for the poor title. Wasn't sure exactly how to word my question.
I have code below which uses a list of tuples called `propadd`. The `if statement` tests the tuples for matching conditions. If the match matches to only 1 tuple from the list of tuples, it executes the exact same code as that in the if statement so as to assign this matching tuple to variable v in order to update the cursor rows with values from this matching tuple. I would like to know if there's a way to get rid of the assignment of the exact same code to v after the if statement. Is it possible to assign the list to v in the if statement while checking for the length of the matches? This is part of a larger amount of code that follows this methodology. I believe that doing this will make my code faster.

```
if len([item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]) == 1:
        v=[item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]
        row1[1]=v[0][1]
        row1[2]=v[0][2]
elif len([item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4]]) == 1:
        k=[item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4]]
        row1[1]=k[0][1]
        row1[2]=k[0][2]
elif len([item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group()]) == 1
        m=[item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group()]
        row1[1]=m[0][1]
        row1[2]=m[0][2]
```

Comment: if you want to make your code faster, i believe using `filter` function is faster than list comp. as i was typing, @MadPhysicist posted what i was going to say: you might as well assign `v` then check `len(v)` so the list comp only runs once

Comment: I'll look into the `filter` function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will make your code slightly faster, and what is much more important, more readable and less error prone. Whether the list you create passes the test `len(...) == 1` or not, it is computed. So why not just compute it once? Of course you will have to replace `elif` with `else-if`:

```
# Compute v
v = [item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]
if len(v) == 1:
    row1[1]=v[0][1]
    row1[2]=v[0][2]
else:
    # If v fails, compute k
    k = [item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4]]
    if len(k) == 1:
        row1[1]=k[0][1]
        row1[2]=k[0][2]
    else:
        # If k fails, compute m
        m = [item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group()]
        if len(m) == 1:
            row1[1]=m[0][1]
            row1[2]=m[0][2]
```

Coming from C, this is much more cumbersome than `if(v = (....)) { } else ...`. However, there is another way to do this. You can use the fact that each expression in the list comprehensions is a generator:

```
v = (item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500)
k = (item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4])
m = (item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group())
for gen in (v, k, m):
    l = list(gen)
    if len(l) == 1:
        row1[1] = l[0][1]
        row1[2] = l[0][2]
        break
```

In this case, the expressions `v`, `k`, `m` are generators, which are objects that are lazily evalutated iterables. They are not actually computing the list. You can go through each one and assign the one that matches when it is found, ignoring the others. The list is not computed until the statement `l = list(gen)`. I think the second approach is much more Pythonic because it uses a single `for` loop no matter how many conditions you have, instead of a sequence of `else` statements marching off the page.

Comment: I have 5 other elif that check for different conditions for 700,000 rows. In that case I would have to define the "v"s outside the if and elifs. (These variables test for different conditions from this v). That really slows down the code if these are computed for each row yet I would like for these v variables to only be computed if the row fails on the first if and preceeding elifs so that they aren't created every time.

Comment: You do realize that if `len([item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500]) == 1` computes the value of `v` and passes it to `len()`? All I did was assign a pointer to the list to a temporary variable.

Comment: Also, do not try to optimize your code until you have run it and know that there is a problem. Readability is a much more important concern up front than optimization.

Comment: If this is not really the question you are asking, post the real code you need help and ask again. This may be an example of the XY problem.

Comment: And finally, you can always replace `elif` with a legitimate `else-if` and precompute the variables inside the `else`s only once the outer if fails.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the elif. The first elif and the rest of them aren't checking for `v`. They check for different conditions ie the `k` variable code is different from `v`. If I assign the `v` and `k` before the loop,`k` will be computed for a row that matches v which I am trying to avoid as it slows down the program.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a redo of the latest version of your code.

Comment: Huh! interesting!! I'll try this method and see what the performance is like.

Comment: Performance is really not that bad. I am gonna accept your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One more question on using the list generator.So after generating `l = list(gen)` and ` if len(l) == 1` What if I wanted to assign text to a row based on the list variable. E.g for `v`, `row1[3]="value 1"` for `k`, `row1[3]="value 2"`,and for `m`, `row1[3]="value 3"`. How would I code that?

Comment: Ask a new question. You are welcome to use my existing code as if it were your own, including posting it in the question.

Comment: I posted a new question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578676/assign-differing-values-to-list-generator-results