# Assign differing values to list generator results

Tags: python, list, generator, arcpy

I am using list generators as shown below. I would like to know how I can assign different text or values to the individual list generators. In the sample code, I can only assign values for all the list generators at once. For example, I would like to assign for `v`, `row1[3]="value 1"`, for `k`,`row1[3]="value 2"` and for `m`, `row1[3]="value 3".` How can I acheive that?

```
v = (item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500)
k = (item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4])
m = (item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group())
for gen in (v, k, m):
    l = list(gen) 
    if len(l) == 1:
        row1[1] = l[0][1]
        row1[2] = l[0][2]
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways of assigning additional values to the different generators. The easiest would be to have a dictionary keyed by the generator or an iterable of the same length containing the values.  Both approaches are shown here:

**Iterable**

```
v = (item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500)
k = (item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4])
m = (item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group())
extraValues = ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value3')
for ind, gen in enumerate((v, k, m)):
    l = list(gen) 
    if len(l) == 1:
        row1[1] = l[0][1]
        row1[2] = l[0][2]
        row1[3] = extraValues[ind]
        break
```

**Dictionary**

```
v = (item for item in propadd if item[0]==row1[8] and harversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<1500)
k = (item for item in custadd if item[0]==row1[4])
m = (item for item in numlist if re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) is not None and item[0]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group())
extraValues = {v: 'value 1',
               k: 'value 2',
               m: 'value3')
for gen in (v, k, m):
    l = list(gen) 
    if len(l) == 1:
        row1[1] = l[0][1]
        row1[2] = l[0][2]
        row1[3] = extraValues[gen]
        break
```

You could also have some complex scenario where the extra value could be generated by some function other than a dictionary lookup or tuple index.

Comment: This works perfect and significantly improves performance. Thank you!!

Comment: Which one did you end up using?

Comment: The speed appeared to be about the same for both so I went with the dictionary because I am more familiar with it and it would be easier for me to assign more differing values if needed.

Comment: I agree that it is the better approach. The tuple basically acts as a dictionary keyed by the index of the generator, which is clearly more error prone since you can switch the indices at any time.